# Insert range of values into mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, multiple-columns

I need to insert range of values into my database table.
User will select a range .... e.g:20 to 100 ...
So the numbers ranging from 20 to 100 must be added into the table in separate rows....How can i implement this using php script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$startIndex = 20;
$endIndex = 100;

while($startIndex <= $endIndex)
{
    $query = $pdo->prepare("Insert into table (field1) values (?)");
    $query->bindValue(1,$startIndex);
    $startIndex++;
    $query->execute();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
  // Dummy values
  $startCount = 45;
  $endCount = 100;
  while ($startCount <= $endCount) {
    $resultInsert = mysql_query("INSERT into tableName (columnName1,columnName2)".
                                " values ('$value1', '$value2')");
    $startCount++;
  }
?>
```